# How to check if username already exist in database collection MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making post request on registration,But I want error to pop up if username is already taken.
Any suggestions?

Here is my post route:

```
   app.post('/addUser', (req,res) => {
    const addUser = new User({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password})
    addUser.save().then(result => res.status(200).json(result)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
})
```

Comment: my personal solution to a similar thing was from the front end. On input i would do a get and search by username. If there was a result gave an error and if not gave an ok that it was available.

Comment: I was thinking about findOne method

Comment: you could do something like.... standby, on mobile. making me mad. back with code in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findOne` method of `mongoose`

```
app.post('/addUser', async (req,res) => {

   //validation
   var { username, password } = req.body;

 //checking username exists
  const existUsername = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username});
   if (existUsername) {
     console.log('username taken');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternate method, depending on the error style you want.

```
const users = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {type: String, unique: 'That username is already taken'}
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

Now mongo will index usernames and check it before the insertion. An error will be thrown if it's not unique.

Comment: both ways work. It's all in what you want to achieve from the error you have.